# jQuery run function onload and key up

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have the following, which I would like to run for the first time when the page loads. Then I would like it to run on keyup as user makes changes. The function I would like to run is very large (stripped down for posting on here) so I don't want to duplicate the function. Is there a way to call the function onload and then reuse it on keyup? Thank you

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     // this calculates the sum for some text nodes
     $("td, input").keyup(
        function (){
          var col_1revenue = $(".Col1Receipts, .Col1Receipts input").sum(); 
        } // function
      ); // keyup
    }); // document ready
```

Comment: dont forget to mark it as accepted if you got the info you want..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    XX();
    // this calculates the sum for some text nodes
    $("td, input").keyup(XX); // keyup


    function XX() {
        var col_1revenue = $(".Col1Receipts, .Col1Receiptsinput").sum();
    } // function    
}); // document ready​​​
```

Answer (score 6):

An easy way is to create a function and then call it from both:

`keyupfunction()` is called the first time the page load completes and when the keyup event gets fired... that is the whole purpose of using a function in a programming language.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         keyupfunction(); //first call
         // this calculates the sum for some text nodes
         $("td, input").keyup(keyupfunction); // keyup
        }); // document ready
```

common function

```
function keyupfunction(){
              var col_1revenue = $(".Col1Receipts, .Col1Receipts input").sum(); 
} // function
```

Answer (score 2):

You could trigger the event once on load.

```
$("td, input").keyup(
  function (){
    var col_1revenue = $(".Col1Receipts, .Col1Receipts input").sum(); 
  } 
).keyup();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a function in multiple places, don't make it anonymous. Anonymous functions are a pain to reuse (you still can reuse them in certain cases via `callee` (deprecated), etc.)

Name the function, instead. Keep it inside the scope of `ready` to be clean:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     // this calculates the sum for some text nodes
     function myfunc(){
          var col_1revenue = $(".Col1Receipts, .Col1Receipts input").sum(); 
           //etc
             //etc
        } // function
     $("td, input").keyup(myfunc); // keyup
     myfunc()//call function;
    }); // document ready
```